# Nginx Wordpress issue with REST Api 401

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, nginx

I have migrated from shared LAMP hosting to VPS NGINX and faced an issue with wordpress REST Api, when I try to get /wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ it response with error:

```
{
  "code": "rest_forbidden",
  "message": "You are not currently logged in.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

But when I request woocommerce REST Api it works fine.
On Apache server all works fine.
Permalinks are enabled.
Have tried to add rewrite rules

```
rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /index.php?rest_route=/$1 last;
```

But it has no effect

Comment: I have same issue, did you find any solution ?